# Python and Name Entity Recognition for Arabic Language

Tags: python, internationalization, nlp, ubuntu-14.04

I am performing some NER on Arabic language.  The code is as follows:

```
from polyglot.text import Text
blob = "مرحبا اسمي rahul agnihotri أنا عمري 41 سنة و الهندية"
text = Text(blob)
text = Text(blob, hint_language_code='ar') #ar stands for arabic
print(text.entities)
```

After executing above given code in ubuntu i get below given error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd9' in file ./ner.py on line 4,
>   but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for
>   details

However, if I include # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- it works and here is the output:

```
[I-LOC([u'\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0646\u062f\u064a\u0629'])]
```

This is not the desired ouptut i am looking for.  The desired output should in Arabic language not this way.

FYI:  All required libraries are installed.

Comment: Probably, you should output the text in a suitable unicode encoding for the platform that you are running on.

Answer (score 1):

Utf-8 encoded text must be decoded. What you're seeing when you print is the encoding. So it must be decoded.
I am not familiar with polyglot, and I cannot confirm this, but please try this.

if you want to eliminate the file encoding dependency then after you set Blob, use: 
blob.encode('utf-8')
and then later to decode the utf-8 for print use:
print(text.entities.decode('utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

in python, you can get the Arabic text again by decoding these bytes

```
Str = "\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0646\u062f\u064a\u0629";
Str = Str.encode('UTF-8','strict');

print (Str.decode("utf-8"))
```

the output will be

```
الهندية
```

I hope this is what you are looking for